# why static dispatch so quickly in swift

Tags: swift, static, dispatch

I know that there is a methods list in class. And I also know the mechanism of dynamic dispatch. But I confused with static dispatch. Where are static methods in. Whether static methods in a global hash table. And how does the static dispatch work. What does the flow like.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are confusing two separate concepts.

Static dispatch refers to the way a method body is called at runtime. If you have a class that could potentially have subclasses or any object where all you know about it is that it conforms to a certain protocol, you have to use dynamic dispatch, which means you have to look up the address of the method in a table (called a vtable or a witness table) and then jump to that location. If the compiler knows exactly what kind of object it has, e.g. a `struct`, a `final` class or a `final` method in a class, it knows the method cannot be overridden and can therefore directly jump to its address without doing the lookup.

A method that is declared `static` is a type method. It will be called on the type itself rather than an instance of the type i.e. inside the method `self` refers to the type not an instance of the type.

`static` methods can't be overridden so the compiler always knows the address at compile time and will use static dispatch for them. There's no need for any kind of hash table or witness table.

Comment: The witness table is used for structs right? If we got a protocol with static method and a few structs implements that, the witness table must be involved right?

Comment: Like you say "if the compiler knows exactly what... therefore directly jump to its address without doing the lookup", how can compiler know the address or where the address save in. And I think "jump to the location in vtable method" is also quickly, why all people say its complex. @JeremyP

Comment: @dowZhang The compiler can know the direct location of the method because it has either just compiled the method (or will be compiling it) or it knows it is linked from another module and the module's metadata will tell the linker exactly where the method is. The compiler only doesn't know the location of the method if the object is a class instance and the method could be overridden or the compiler only knows it is an object conforming to a protocol.